# Games for education

Tags: education, games

I'm searching an Open Data (free code) for Education Games, like Puzzle. Actually, I need a game that presents the context information and which is the educative game for the children. I would like to use it for demonstrating the MAKEY MAKEY Kit.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are asking. Are looking for a data set or a open source game?

Comment: In fact, it is to have a complete game (I do not have much time to program) .I thought to help anyone with any codes ready.

I mean a game for children - educational puzzle though. Or for example - User has three monkeys which have to click it to correspond to words. A simple question: what is this? Crocodiles? The answer is correct and the player succeeds at the highest stage .Also will win points.